# Particle Time Taken

Tags: physics

A lecturer of mine gave me and my colleagues this question to solve.

A particle is attracted towards a fix point $O$, with a force inversely proportional to its instantaneous distance from $O$.  If the particle is released from rest,  find the time taken for it to reach $O$.

I couldn't figure out where to begin, pls help. Thanks.

Comment: You could use conservation of energy to get the velocity as a function of distance and then $\int \frac{1}{v}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Put the origin of the $x$ axis at the center of attraction. In the initial position the partical is at some distance $x=s$. Use the second Newton’s law:

$$m\ddot x=-\frac{k}{x}$$

...where $m$ represents the mass of the particle and $k$ is some constant.

$$m\dot x\frac{d\dot x}{dx}=-\frac{k}{x}$$

$$\frac 12m\dot x^2=-k\ln x+C$$

In the initial position $x=s$ velocity is zero. This gives:

$$C=k\ln s$$

$$\frac 12m\dot x^2=k\ln\frac{s}{x}$$

$$\dot x=-\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}\ln\frac sx}$$

Minus sign is necessary because the distance between the particle and the attractor is decreasing.

$$\frac {dx}{dt}=-\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}\ln\frac sx}$$

$$dt=-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}\ln\frac sx}}$$

$$T=-\sqrt\frac{m}{2k}\int_s^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\ln\frac sx}}$$

Introduce substitution:

$$\ln\frac sx=u, \ \ dx=-se^{-u}du$$

$$T=s\sqrt\frac{m}{2k}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt u}du$$

$$T=s\sqrt\frac{m\pi}{2k}$$